# How to avoid bit representation in CAN implementation

Tags: microcontroller, can

I am bit confused with the following problem i am implementing CAN driver but in that there are some signals less than 1 byte and some are even single bit which are defined as part of dbc file. But the C standard such as Misra says you cannot use bit size variables as they are not portable. How can i overcome this problem?

Comment: Pad your sub-byte variables out to bytes. If you have  multiple such variables which you are attempting to send in a single message, concatenate them into byte-sized packets.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If possible can you just guide me such that by seeing the signal variable i should also be able to say the length of signal.

Comment: Sorry? You're using C, so every variable is declared and type established. Look up any beginner's text on C and you'll find a list of variable sizes right at the beginning.

Comment: Sorry i mean to say something like this struct msg_tag{ uint8 signal:3} if i do bit representation i know the signal length is 3. But i make it byte then it will be struct can_msg{uint8 signal}. Here i don't know the size of signal.  Ok i will try to incorporate in the signal name like struct can_msg{uint8 signal_len_3bits}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you begin, consider that you're writing code for a *specific* piece of hardware. Your code will not be 100% portable almost by definition.

More to the topic, the standard way of portable bit field access is by using bit masks and shifts:

```c
// not portable
struct bit_field {
  unsigned int x : 1;
  unsigned int y : 3;
  unsigned int z : 4;
} bits;
bits.y = 2;

// portable
#define X_MASK 0x1U
#define X_SHIFT 0U
#define Y_MASK 0xEU
#define Y_SHIFT 1U
#define Z_MASK 0xF0U
#define Z_SHIFT 4U
unsigned int bits;
bits = (bits & ~Y_MASK) | (2U << Y_SHIFT);
```

Comment: Avoid using signed types for bit arithmetic. Code like `2 << n` can cause undefined behavior if `n` is close to the max size of an `int`. Similarly, `~0xe` will cause a change in signedness which could cause unexpected bugs. The solution is to use `u` suffix on all integer constants or cast them to the proper type.

Comment: @Lundin good point.